# PHP echo from db by id

Tags: php, mysql

How do I echo a user's name and his specific country? Like this:

*Account name: leo*

*Country: Germany*

The account name is working.

PHP at the top of the page is:

```
<?php 
    session_start(); 

    if (!isset($_SESSION['username'])) {
        $_SESSION['msg'] = "You must log in first";
        header('location: login.php');
    }

    if (isset($_GET['logout'])) {
        session_destroy();
        unset($_SESSION['username']);
        header("location: login.php");
    }
?>
```

Connect to database (seperate file server.php):

```
$db = mysqli_connect('localhost', 'root', '', 'registration');
```

HTML:

```
<li class="p-li">Account name: <?php echo $_SESSION['username']; ?></li>
<li class="p-li">Country:<?php echo $_a['a']; ?> </li>
```

[image: My database]

Comment: I don't think I understand the question. Are you looking for help with a SQL query? or creating whatever $_a is? or something else?

Comment: You need to write a query to get the country by username.

Comment: Do you want to show current logged in user data?

Comment: @Wiliam_Wilson SQL_query

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to define $_a at the moment it doesn't appear to be referencing anything so would be blank. Forgetting that though you asked about SQL query in the comments.

SQL Query would be

```
$id = $_SESSION['username'];   

"SELECT Country FROM registration WHERE username='%".id."%'"
```

Please be aware that's just a snippet of code as you said you wanted the SQL query. I defined $id as the users username as you said you wanted to get country by username, I would though recommend you use the id column of the table as this will always be unique.